# Find extreme values of $f$ subject to both constraints. $f=z; g=x^2+y^2=z^2; h=x+y+z=24$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

$f=z \\
g=x^2+y^2=z^2\\ 
h=x+y+z=24$

I'm having a hard time soloing out $\mu, \lambda, x, y,$ or $z$.

$\triangle(f)=\langle0,0,1\rangle\\
\triangle(g)=\langle2x, 2y, -2z\rangle\\
\triangle(h)=\langle1,1,1\rangle$

$
f_x = 0 = \lambda 2x + \mu 1 \rightarrow x=-\frac{\mu 1}{\lambda 2}\\
f_y = 0 = \lambda 2y + \mu 1 \rightarrow y=-\frac{\mu 1}{\lambda 2}\\
f_z = 1 = -\lambda 2z + \mu 1 \rightarrow z=\frac{\mu 1}{\lambda 2}+1
$

If I plug my variables back into $h$, I get $-\frac{\mu 1}{\lambda 2}=25$, this is where I get stuck. I can't say $x=y=-\frac{\mu 1}{\lambda 2}=25$ because that wouldn't work with $g$. I'm at a loss of what to do next.

For the record, this is for Calc III exam prep, **not** for homework.

Comment: You already know that $x=y$ and that $z=1-y$, you could try plugging these into $h$ to solve for $y$

Comment: $f_z: 1 = -2\lambda z + \mu  \implies z=\frac{\mu}{2 \lambda}-\frac {1}{2\lambda}$

Comment: @DougM you are right

Comment: These problems can be simplified with symmetry. Note that we can switch $x$ and $y$ in $g$ and end up with the same thing. Also the same with $x$ and $y$ in $h$. So we can in conclude that the extreme value occurs somewhere along $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

$x = y\\
2x+z = 24\\
2x^2 = z^2\\
x = \pm \frac {\sqrt 2}{2} z$

$(1+\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}) z = 24, (1-\frac {\sqrt 2}{2}) z = 24\\
z = \frac {48}{2+\sqrt2}, z = \frac {48}{2-\sqrt2}\\
z = \frac 24(2-\sqrt2), z = 24(2+\sqrt2)\\
$

Comment: Those $z$ values you found are local extremes. They are not global extremes. There are no maximum, and no minimum. The function $f$ subject to these conditions is unbounded with inf $f=-\infty$, sup $f=\infty$.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4410778/do-absolute-maxima-and-minima-exist-in-this-question